# Actions in kleopatra result in general error

Tags: pgp

I have setup a fresh kubuntu 16.10 installation from cd. I have a seperate home volume (physically and logically) which is mounted at start.

After installing kleopatra I am not able to do anything that is related to keys. Everything results in *Error: General Error*. Digging into the KWatchGnuPG showed the following:

```
gpg-agent[1770]: DBG: chan_7 -> ERR 67109139 Unknown IPC Command <GPG Agent>
```

I did some research already in the internet, but nothing currently helps.

Thanks for your help,
school_guy

P.S.: Here is the full action log of trying to set the trust in kleopatro to "My own certificate"

```
4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: Handhabungsroutine 0x7ff5d632b700 für fd 7 gestartet
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK Pleased to meet you, process 12907
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- RESET
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- OPTION display=:0
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- OPTION xauthority=/tmp/xauth-1000-_0
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- OPTION putenv=DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-uqvbhOn2r5,guid=08255fcf0c7b94827f6a0e3a58f498fb
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- GETINFO version
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> D 2.1.15
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- OPTION allow-pinentry-notify
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- OPTION agent-awareness=2.1.0
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- AGENT_ID
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> ERR 67109139 Unbekanntes IPC Kommando <GPG Agent>
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- HAVEKEY SOMESTUFF
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- HAVEKEY SOMESTUFF
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- HAVEKEY SOMESTUFF
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- HAVEKEY SOMESTUFF
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 -> OK
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: DBG: chan_7 <- [eof]
  4 - 2017-04-17 14:46:00 gpg-agent[1803]: Handhabungsroutine 0x7ff5d632b700 für den fd 7 beendet
```

Comment: How and when is the separate home directory mounted?

Comment: at boot, in the normal way with the fstab file

Comment: That should work out, just wanted to be sure that you're not mounting during logon while `gpg-agent` might already be started (and still seing some files before the directory is mounted). But mounting during system boot should be fine.

Comment: Ok, any idea where the error comes from and how it is resolved?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. You could try running `killall gpg-agent` and see if that helps (it should be restarted afterwards), but I do not see any obvious issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved after using Kubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I was not able to solve this issue under Kubuntu 16.10 and 17.10. But now everything works like a charm.

UPDATE: 06.12.17
Now it is working also under Kubuntu 16.10 and 17.10. Just a new fresh install worked. Upgrading the LTS failed (in relation to Kleopatra).